# Sum of average of all subarrays

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics

Suppose there is an integer array $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. Calculate the sum of average of all subarrays. For example, the sum of average of all subarrays of array $[1,3,5]$ is $1+3+5+\frac{1+3}{2}+\frac{3+5}{2}+\frac{1+3+5}{3} = 18$

I'm wondering does it exist an $O(n)$ algorithm?

Comment: We're not looking for questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

This sum is a linear combination of the array elements, with varying weights .

In the case of four elements,
$$a+b+c+d+\frac{a+b}2+\frac{b+c}2+\frac{c+d}2+\frac{a+b+c}3+\frac{b+c+d}3+\frac{a+b+c+d}4$$

$$a:1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14$$

$$b:1+\frac22+\frac23+\frac14$$

and symmetrically for $c,d$.

If precomputing these coefficients for the required $n$ is allowed, the solution is indeed $O(n)$. Otherwise, the pattern is a sum of fractions with denominators that are the naturals and the numerators follow a triangle wave. I guess that these can be computed efficiently by computing the prefix sum of the inverses of the naturals, then accumulating the terms incrementally, in total time $O(n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Actually, I'm continuously thinking how to calculate the contribution of each different length, and how will it contribute to the answer when add a new element $a[i]$.Your solution actually considers the contribution of each element in the array.

Comment: @BlablaW: I answered the stated question. I did not answer the hidden one, sorry.

Comment: HahaThat's not a problem. What I said is my idea, which may be wrong. I think you just solved it perfectly. The modular inverse of [1,2,...,n] can be linearly calculated and also its prefix sum. And the pattern of this triangular wave can easily be summed up. So I posted the c++ code just now on the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is provided by [Yves Daoust](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/16034/yves-daoust).

Here is the C++ code I implemented just now.
The input format is like

```
n
a_1 a_2 ... a_n
```

The modular number is $10^9+7$.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
constexpr int mod = 1e9+7;
void solve(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> a(n+1);
    vector<int> inv(n+1);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;++i) cin>>a[i];
    inv[1] = 1;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;++i) // linearly calculate mod inverse of [1,2,...,n]
        inv[i] = 1LL * (mod-mod/i)*inv[mod%i]%mod;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;++i) // prefix of mod inverse of [1,2,...,n]
        inv[i] = (1LL * inv[i] + inv[i-1])%mod;
    int ans = 0;
    int tot = 0;
    int r = n, l = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=(n+1)/2;++i){
        tot = (1LL * tot + inv[r--] - inv[l++] + mod) % mod;
        ans = (1LL * ans + 1LL * a[i] * tot ) % mod;
    }
    if(n%2==0) ans = (1LL * ans + 1LL * a[n/2+1] * tot) % mod;
    for(int i=(n+1)/2+1+(n%2==0);i<=n;++i){
        tot = (1LL * tot - inv[++r] + inv[--l] + mod) % mod;
        ans = (1LL * ans + 1LL * a[i] * tot) % mod;
    }
    cout<<ans<<'\n';
}
```